# Issues with https and Service Fabric

Tags: https, azure-service-fabric

While trying to implement https on our ServiceFabric backend, following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint) guide, I found my local cluster throwing following error:

> There was an error during CodePackage activation.The service host
>   terminated with exit code:1

and sometimes the following would pop up:

> fabric:/Dev.Project/Api is not ready, 1
>   partitions remaining. => Something is taking too long, the application
>   is still not ready.

In the Diagnostic Events I find this

```
{
  "Timestamp": "2018-08-20T12:01:21.6423999+02:00",
  "ProviderName": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric",
  "Id": 23083,
  "Message": "ApplicationHostTerminated:   ApplicationId=fabric:/Dev.Project,  ServiceName=fabric:/Dev.Project/Api,  ServicePackageName=ApiPkg,  ServicePackageActivationId=1d4426dc-3d5e-41ea-aa44-6e9794ff7c69,  IsExclusive=True,  CodePackageName=Code,  EntryPointType=Exe,  ExeName=Setup.bat,  ProcessId=29024,  HostId=77c22be7-b993-46c6-92dd-7c7ed0c8af1c,  ExitCode=1,  UnexpectedTermination=True,  StartTime=12:01:21.568939 (151,099.982 MSec). ",
  "ProcessId": 25768,
  "Level": "Informational",
  "Keywords": "0x4000000000000001",
  "EventName": "Hosting",
  "ActivityID": null,
  "RelatedActivityID": null,
  "Payload": {
    "eventInstanceId": "6dbdc967-85ed-429a-ae6a-939aeeea1e3f",
    "applicationName": "fabric:/Dev.Project",
    "ServiceName": "fabric:/Dev.Project/Api",
    "ServicePackageName": "ApiPkg",
    "ServicePackageActivationId": "1d4426dc-3d5e-41ea-aa44-6e9794ff7c69",
    "IsExclusive": true,
    "CodePackageName": "Code",
    "EntryPointType": 1,
    "ExeName": "Setup.bat",
    "ProcessId": 29024,
    "HostId": "77c22be7-b993-46c6-92dd-7c7ed0c8af1c",
    "ExitCode": 1,
    "UnexpectedTermination": true,
    "StartTime": "2018-08-20T12:01:21.5689395+02:00"
  }
}
```

The Id being the Id of my Api-service. It probably has something to do with the Setup.bat that's not being executed correctly, or errors are thrown while running it, but I can't figure out what to do about it. As stated in the guide, I added the

```
<Principals>
  <Users>
    <User Name="SetupAdminUser">
      <MemberOf>
        <SystemGroup Name="Administrators" />
      </MemberOf>
    </User>
  </Users>
</Principals>
```

part, and added the RunAsPolicy to the service as well

```
<ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="ApiPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
  <ConfigOverrides>
    <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
      ...
    </ConfigOverride>
  </ConfigOverrides>
  <EnvironmentOverrides CodePackageRef="Code">
    ...
  </EnvironmentOverrides>
  <Policies>
    <RunAsPolicy CodePackageRef="Code" UserRef="SetupAdminUser" EntryPointType="Setup" />
  </Policies>
</ServiceManifestImport>
```

I searched all over, but I can't find what the problem is. Any input is welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the part with the Setup.bat? In a mean time can you check the locale of the VM with node? This can be the reason because in different OS languages the 'Administrators' group has different name.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
I have added LocalSystem instead of Admin user.

```
 <Policies>
  <RunAsPolicy CodePackageRef="Code" UserRef="SetupLocalSystem" EntryPointType="Setup" />
</Policies>

 <Principals>
<Users>
  <User Name="SetupLocalSystem" AccountType="LocalSystem" />
</Users>
```

Also take care of DNS name in SetCertAccess.ps1 file, it should be same as cluster name.

```
$subject="your cluster DNS name"
```